# Referencing an ArrayListin another class? Java/Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I need some help with data management. Hopefully I can explain this well enough. I create and instantiate an ArrayList in Class A, but I want to display the data in Class B. It is a little trickier than this, let me explain my steps.

I created some setters and getters in Class A

```
public static void setArray(ArrayList<String> list) {
   ClassA.mList = list;
}

public static ArrayList<String> getArray() {
   return mList;
}
```

While in Class A, I populate my array with one item, mList.add("item"). Now that I have an item in my list (mList), I start a new Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ClassA.this, ClassB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I purposefully did not finish() this Activity. Now that I am in Class B, I test if the data persists by printing out the first item in the array using my getter method.

```
System.out.println("Data persists? " + ClassA.getArray().get(0));
```

Everything works fine up to this point. But now I finish() Class B, which brings me back to Class A. I added in onResume() for Class A to add another item to my list (mList) and thenI start the second Activity (Class B) again. I then use recursion to check if I have two items in my arraylist, and there is only 1. I also checked in onResume if I could print out anything, and the size of mList is 0. My guess is that it re-instantiated, and reset the list?

How can I maintain data in an ArrayList after leaving the Activity and then returning back? I want to be able to add/update data to that arraylist every time I return back to Class A

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use static methods to share non-static data between activities. For this purpose please use Intent you passing as temporary storage of your data. For example you provided you can refer to [putStringArrayListExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks for the suggestion!